# Finding the char index of a Font Style in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm looking for an efficient way to find the character indexes of different font styles in a RichTextBox.  I have the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
   _activeCopyBox.Select(i, 1);

   if (!linkFound && _activeCopyBox.SelectionFont.Underline)
      underLineFound = true;
}
```

This however is very slow as it has to select each letter one at a time.  I can get the formatting out of the Rft but it is messy trying to find the correct index of the charater this way.

If someone knows a better way (there must be one) I'd love to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the .Rtf property, this gives you the underlying RTF information including all the special tags and such that ultimately underlines and bolds and otherwise formats the information in the RichTextBox.

Here's a link to the RTF markup that will probably help with whatever your trying to do, much more efficiently:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28office.10%29.aspx

Search for 'underline' and 'bold' and you'll see how it works. Most likely need to use Regular Expressions to get at the information you want quickly and efficiently as well.

Comment: Regex is quite reliable for counting font styles. Finding the exact char index is problematic as you have to convert the RTF to plain text.